# Python - Can I distribute tickets to employees with 2 lists?

Tags: python

I have a class called `Ticket` and a class called `Employee`,
Instances of the classes are stored in 2 different lists.

```
employee_objects = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
ticket_objects = ["ticket1", "ticket2", "ticket3", "ticket4", "ticket5","ticket6", "ticket7", "ticket8"]

class Ticket:
    def __init__(self, ticket_number):
        self.ticket_number = ticket_number
        
class Employee: 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.asigned_tickets = []
```

basically I want to distribute the tickets evenly to the employees and add the ticket to `self.asigned_ticket` list. So that I can call `Employee.name + Employee.asigned_tickets` and see the name and assigned tickets.

Comment: For now the lists contains string, not instances of your classes, careful

Comment: Yes, i just wrote this code with strings, but in my program, instances are stored within, i just didn't want to copy 50 lines of code and make it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. First step is to create instances of your tickets and employees.

```py
employees = [Employee(employee_name) for employee_name in employee_objects]
tickets = [Ticket(number) for number in ticket_objects]
```

Then you can distribute them round-robin pretty easily.

```py
import itertools

for emp, tick in zip(itertools.cycle(employees), tickets):
    emp.assigned_tickets.append(tick)
```

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) Creates an iterator of infinite length that cycles through the input. `cycle('ABCD') -> A B C D A B C D A B C D A B ...`

`zip` pairs two collections together. Since `tickets` is finite, we can trust that it will terminate the zip (contrast `itertools.zip_longest` which will extend the shorter collections to match the length of the longest one)

Let's write some tests!

```py
# mymodule.py

import itertools
import typing

class Employee():
    def __init__(self, name, tickets=None):
        self.name = name
        self.tickets = tickets if tickets is not None else []

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.name == other.name and self.tickets == other.tickets

def distribute_roundrobin(employees: typing.List[Employee], items: typing.List[typing.Any]):
    """
    Distribute round-robin across all recipients, looping where necessary.

    >>> employees = [Employee("name") for _ in range(3)]
    >>> distribute_roundrobin(employees, 'ABCDEFGHIJ')
    >>> expected = [
    ... Employee('name', ['A', 'D', 'G', 'J']),
    ... Employee('name', ['B', 'E', 'H']),
    ... Employee('name', ['C', 'F', 'I']),
    ... ]
    >>> employees == expected
    True
    """

    for emp, item in zip(itertools.cycle(employees), items):
        emp.tickets.append(item)
```

```
# from /bin/bash or etc
$ python -m doctest mymodule.py
```

Comment: For the first step was done in my code but thank you for the list comprehension, for the second part that works perfect, thanks a lot !

Comment: @loiclegrand it's not in your question, so it's not done as far as SO is concerned! :)

Comment: Yeah excuse me, that worked fine thanks for the help ! :)